# How can I filter data for visualization (bar plot) in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, filter, bar-chart

[image: Data]

Trying to create a bar plot in python for the data shown in the photo. I am creating the plot for the Job-Type column, but I need to filter the data so that 'Degree Status' == 'HS-grad' and 'Earnings' = '<=50K'.

I was able to plot the bar chart for 'Job-Type' using the following code:

[image: plot for job-type]

Is there any function or code I can use to filter the data?

I am able to get it in a table format using this code:

```
df[df['Degree Status'].str.contains('HS-grad') & df['Earnings'].str.contains('<=50K')]
```

But I need to visualize it.

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = df[df['Degree Status'].str.contains('HS-grad') & df['Earnings'].str.contains('<=50K')]

df1['Job-Role'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```